# Displaying a subcategory field along with suggestions in apachesolr autocomplete drupal 7

Tags: search

I am using **apachesolr_autocomplete** module of **Drupal 7** to implement the search functionality on my website(supermarket website). But now i want to implement a functionality to show subcategories as well in the search suggestions. Suppose user searches for 'ipho', then the autocomplete suggestions should be :

1. 'iphone in mobiles'
2. 'iphone in mobile covers' etc.

I have indexed the category field but couldn't find any way to get this done. Also the D7 docs for apachesolr didn't help much.